# Information sets in cyclic codes

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, coding-theory

I am trying to show that in any cyclic code of dimension k, any set of k consecutive coordinates forms an information set. I think the argument can be made by considering the parity check matrix, but I am not sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: what is a "set of k consecutive coordinates"

Comment: k consecutive codeword locations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is true. A plan:

- Show that it holds for the $k$ last coordinates (Hint: what happens when you use the generator polynomial and do systematic encoding).
- Apply cyclicity to show that it holds for any $k$ consecutive coordinates (including the shifts that "wrap around").

Comment: I think I understand your approach. But these would mean that the code has a different generator matrix for each set of k consecutive coordinates; is it not? I want to know if one can retain the same generator matrix and if for this generator matrix, any k consecutive coordinates can be used as an information set.

Comment: Oh, I finally see what Mr Lahtonen means.... As of OP's requirement of same generator matrix but each k consecutive coordinates be an information set, this is same as requirement that every k "square region" is a matrix whose rows are linear indep., or that every k "square region" is a matrix whose columns are linear indep., which seems not always true, depending on expression of generator g.

Comment: Actually, i think I have got it. Suppose that we know the value of the codeword on locations $j$ to $j+k-1$ (reduced modulo $n$). We know that there is another codeword that has the same values on the last $k$ coordinates since cyclic shifts of codewords are also codewords. We can perform the shift and decode the corresponding message. The required message can be obtained by shifting backwards by the appropriate amount. This means by knowing the value of the codeword on any $k$ consecutive locations, we can obtain the message vector.

Comment: Good job, @user401163!